# Trying to fix leakage issue in this under-voltage cut-off circuit

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, undervoltage

I have a device that works with EV battery 48 V (40-65 V) input and now I need to cut off my circuit load below 40 V battery voltage to prevent further battery discharge.

I'm trying to simulate an under-voltage cut-off circuit and while the simulation value is not as expected, leakage voltage is there.

How can I fix it? What should I modify in the circuit in order to cut off my circuit at or below 40 V?

[image: Simulation circuit]

Comment: Leakage voltage? Do you mean the voltage across the load when the BJT is deactivated?

Comment: What is the voltage across R3 when your input is just below 40V? When Q1 is OFF, there can still be a small leakage current flowing through it. We need to understand if you are just seeing leakage current or is Q1 partially ON

Comment: What is your load, how much current/power does it use?

Comment: Hi Andy aka, Apologies for the delayed response.
Leakage voltage is what we are getting even MOSFET gate is high across.
Across the R3 the voltage is 65V but I'm not able to off the MOSFET even I varied the Comparator voltage.

Comment: Our load is a kind of tracker device that will consume a maximum of 10W, And our idea is to make the circuit that works as an Undervoltage lockout to prevent further voltage discharge from the battery after a particular threshold voltage(40v).

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the 741 op amp and use an op amp whose output can go to near zero volts. As a result, Q2 is never completely off, resulting in Q1 never being completely off.

Also, in simulation you can try reducing the value of R7. This will also help Q1 turn off more fully.

Comment: Or he use a 1k resistor from the base of Q2 to GND, then he have a voltage divider and must reach only <0.6 Volt. He should use higher values, like 10k or higher as R8. (example: R8=10k to the base and 10k from the base to GND)  The current over the voltage divider (R1, R2, R5, R6) should be much higher.  R4 should be much bigger, around 13k Ohm would be good.

Comment: Thanks Marla for the reply and suggestions.
you noticed right while doing the simulation Q1 is not going OFF even though Q2 is also OFF.  The voltage is always high at the Base of the Q1 transistor.

Can you please suggest OP amp ic whose output can go to near zero?

Comment: Spehro Pefhany below suggested LM358, which is a good choice

Answer (score 2):

The 1N750 is a 4.7V (nominal) zener diode. That's a bit too close to the 5V supply for even a rail-to-rail input op-amp, let alone a 741.

The 741 cannot operate properly from 5V (10V minimum), the input common mode range is not very near either supply, and the output cannot swing near either supply (the negative one being the important one in this case).

Replacing the 741 with 1/2 an LM358 will deal with the supply voltage and the output swing problem but you still need to reduce the reference to something within the common mode range, say 2.5V. So dump the 1N750 and use something like a TL431. I suggest powering the TL431 via a resistor to +5 rather than 65V. You *need* the reference to continue functioning even when the input voltage dips low, and the cheap TL431 needs at least 1mA at all times, which might result in a more wasteful power dissipation in a resistor to 65V that has to maintain 1mA at (say) 20V or 30V. This is actually an important design constraint and should be specified (the battery voltage range over which it is guaranteed to disconnect the load).

It's quite possible to have undesirable behavior at very low (but non-zero) input voltages that could cause problems. For example, if the drive to Q1 dropped into too far and the load was high Q1 could burn up. Or it could oscillate between on and off causing issues with the load (this is a likely outcome near the switching point, even at higher voltages since you have no hysteresis).

As another point, you don't have a current-limiting resistor in series with Q2's base. This is non-optional, and you'll need to calculate it based on the maximum load current. Otherwise you'll destroy Q1 and/or Q2 most likely.

For your simulations, I suggest picking actual transistor models rather than the default of the program you are using. They might have picked some scrawny internal IC transistor as the default rather than a relatively beefy real part.

Comment: Yes, the base resistor is essential. I missed that one Spehro.

Comment: @Marla It's always a challenge to decide where to stop when there are multiple issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a much better, more practical circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPPH3q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Values of resistors are critical, so it's best if they're exact. 
The quiescent current will be at least 1mA, which is over 40 mW constant power drain when the battery is low. 
Q1 can be any PNP transistor that can withstand at least 70V. 
MOSFET can be N-channel type that can withstand at least 70V. 
R1/R2 ratio sets the minimum battery voltage point. 
R4/R3 ratio sets the MOSFET gate voltage (range). 
R6 sets the current at which Q1 and thus MOSFET (output) turns on. 
R5 limits the maximum current through Q1 and TL431 and limits the maximum voltage across TL431 (max. 37V rating for its cathode).

Comment: Thanks for your  input but my doubt is Q1 and MOSFET you took withstand 65 - 70 volts while just want to make sure that i need to keep running my load/ckt till approx 40v so do you mean 65- 70v you are considering as max volt?  , if so then perfect i try to simulate this ckt and on breadboard

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oBeskbY_lk8Le1re8ECRYWrnP3eNbr1z (here is attached simulated file)
i  tried to simulate your ckt but it doesn't shutdown at 36v i want to shutdown it at  aopprox 40v,  what so things to improve it or modify too please let me that what im missing

Comment: @AshuTamar I will try to make it and see if it works as intended. You shouldn't put too much faith in simulations, real-world test is the best if you can do it. These components are easy to find in many places.

Answer (score 0):

You also need hysteresis. A battery's open-circuit voltage is higher than its voltage under load. If your circuit worked as intended, it would just be trying to regulate the load current, rather than cutting it off. You need a circuit that disconnects the load at 40 V and doesn't reconnect until it goes above some higher voltage.

If you're really concerned about leakage you might consider a circuit that checks the voltage every minute or so and otherwise is in some low current-consumption state. Batteries don't discharge insytantaneously.